# unable to stop ajax call on document ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax function which I would like to optionally run as a MVC view is loaded, but I can't stop it from running. I've set a boolean variable to stop the function, but its value is ignored. When I understand why, then I'll try and pass a value from the view model to set true/false - to govern whether or not to call the ajax function when the view loads. The following snippet makes the ajax call even though it seems it shouldn't.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#divLoading").show();
      var doit = false;
      if (doit) {
         CallAjaxPost();
      }
   });
  function CallAjaxPost() {
     var url = '@Url.Action("PostMethod", "Nav")';
     $.post(url, null,
        function (data) {
           $("#PID")[0].innerHTML = data;
           $("#divLoading").hide();
        });
     }
```

Comment: if you don't want to run it on dom ready then why don't you wrap the call within whatever event you're waiting for?

Comment: I do want to run it on dom ready - not waiting for any event. I don't understand why the boolean variable doesn't stop the call

Comment: Once understood, then I intend to replace the variable with a Boolean value in the view model.

Comment: I think you need to add more javascript.  I suspect CallAjaxPost isn't being invoked from where you think it is.  I'd get a debugging tool and put a breakpoint in the CallAjaxPost and then inspect the call stack to see where the call is originating.  If your breakpoint doesn't get hit, try removing the if statement, if it still doesn't get hit, try another debugging tool.

Comment: Thankyou, yes there was an error in my code. I will close this matter shortly. The Boolean variable works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my code. Everything works as expected.